# Fundamental group of the complement of $k$ disjoint lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

What would be the Fundamental Group of the complement of $k$ disjoint lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

If all the $k$ lines passes through the origin, then I know that it is the free group on $2k-1$ generators. If the lines are disjoint and does not pass through the origin, then does the Fundamental Group change? If it is same then how can I show that they are same? Please help!!

Answer (score 4):

You can smoothly and nonintersectingly deform any finite set of nonintersecting lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so that they are all vertical. Your space is now clearly homeomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}^2 \smallsetminus \{p_1, \ldots, p_k\}) \times \mathbb{R}$.

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is nullhomotopic, your space is homotopic to the space $\mathbb{R}^2 \smallsetminus \{p_1, \ldots, p_k\}$, which has the free group $F_k$ as fundamental group.

Comment: Heh, I was writing basically the same answer :)... Cheers!

Comment: Intuitively it is quite clear now..but how can I see this deformation to vertical lines in a mathematical way.. I mean can I explicitly write some formulas which will show this deformation.

Comment: @John Pick a direction that is not orthogonal to any of the lines and stretch the space in that direction, thus making the given lines more and more parallel to this direction

Comment: No, technically we're not allowed to stretch the *space* along that direction, otherwise we get improper limit behavior. We just need to stretch the *holes* in that direction, but keep all the space's points on the same altitude wrt that direction.

Comment: can anyone tell me the arguments in a mathematical way (with some equations) how to do it for 2 lines.

Comment: For two lines, take the unique orthogonal segment. Rotate the second line, using the orthogonal segment as an axis, until it is parallel to the first line.

Comment: By $F_k$, do you mean, the free group in k generators? Don't you?